# Cisco ASA 5505: PAT / NAT between 2 IPSec Tunnels

Tags: cisco, nat, cisco-asa, ipsec, pat

I've the following Setup:

Customer <-> HQ <-> Branchoffice

- The Customer has a 192.168.1.0/24 subnet.
- On the HQ only the VPN Gateway is in my context, 172.20.10.1 .
- And on the Branchoffice side the network 172.30.0.0/16 is present.

Between the HQ <-> Customer, and Branchoffice <-> HQ are IPSec tunnels (Tunnel Mode).

- The HQ <-> Customer Tunnel has 192.168.90.0/30 as source and 192.168.1.0/24 as destination network configured.
- The Branchoffice <-> HQ Tunnel has 172.30.0.0/16 as source and 192.168.1.0/24, 172.20.0.0/16 as destnation.

The reason why i'm using 192.168.90.0/30 as source is that we NAT/PAT every connection through 192.168.90.1 to hide our internal structure to our customer. So i've a NAT rule configured as:

- src interface isp
- dst interface isp
- dst ip 192.168.1.0/24
- pat over 192.168.90.1 / isp interface

that works fine for our roadwarrior vpn (IPSec / L2TP) on the HQ ASA but not for the branchoffice tunnel. The asa is searching for a cryptomap that matches 172.30.30.10 as src and 192.168.1.12 as dst - which can - as expected - not be found. How can i change that routing pakets over PAT from our branchoffice to our customer works?

Additional Info: ASA Software Version 8.2(4) HQ / 8.2(5) branchoffice

Comment: What version of ASA OS are you running?  Also, it is practically impossible to answer questions like this without also seeing the config.  Can you paste a copy of the config (removing any passwords or sensitive data?)

Comment: i thought it might be possible to point out a simple logical fail why the ASA skips the NAT table, but i'll add the configs soon, SW version added